# I have Windows 10 Technical Preview. Will I get any notification to "upgrade" tomorrow?

Tags: windows, windows-10-preview, windows-10-upgrade

Ive been using windows 10 technical preview, and over the past few months I have accumulated a few strange problems, albeit relatively minor problems.  I was wondering if tomorrow I will receive a notification to "upgrade" to windows 10 full release version.

Comment: The notification is only for eligible Windows 7 and Windows 8.1 users.  If you upgraded from one of these installations to the Technical Preview in the preceding months you are already running the RTM build.  If you simply installed the Technical Preview this is also true, you just don't have a retail license, which means you must continue to update your builds before they expire.  This question has been asked several times already, I just don't have duplicate (with a valid current answer), I am trying to decide if this question needs a good answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you’re a Windows Insider and running build 10240 – you already have the Windows 10 we are making available today.ref: http://blogs.windows.com/bloggingwindows/2015/07/28/windows-10-free-upgrade-available-in-190-countries-today/ look at end of speech